# ERROR LOCATING SERVER/INSTANCE SPECIFIED

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing an instance specific error (cannot access to server) while connecting to SQL Server using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. Even if I'm putting the right instance name `Haris-PC\SQLEXPRESS` and `LOCAL`

Comment: What **edition** of SQL Server did you install? SQL Server **Express** defaults to a `SQLEXPRESS` instance name - all other editions default to an unnamed default instance. So if you installed SQL Server **Express**, then `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` is the most logical choice - otherwise try `(local)`

Answer (score 0):

If it is a local server, first check if the SQL server service is enabled. You can also try to simply put a '.' (Dot or Period) as the instance name and see if it is connecting. If it doesn't work, open SQL Server configuration manager and check the correct instance name and use it to connect.

If it is a remote server you are trying to connect to,  check if the SQL Server Browser Service is enabled on the remote server. If that doesn't work, check which port is SQL Server service hosted. The default is port number 1433 but sometimes it's different. If it is other than the default port, you need to explicitly mention the port number along with server.