# Entity Framework connection string - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I'm facing some issues trying to connect to an SQL Server 2005 using Entity Framework.

I've this small *WindowsForm* application using a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername\\sqlhotel;Database=mydatabase;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword");

try
{
    cnn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show ("Connection is Open ");
    cnn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
}
```

This is working fine on my server (I'm getting the "Connection is Open" message), but in my *ASP.NET Web API* application using `Entity Framework 6` I'm getting this error using the above connection string:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Why?

Comment: removing the tags from your question yields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644482/error-locating-server-instance-specified

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that TCP/IP is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager, and that SQL Server is allowed through your Windows Firewall (on the server) if you are trying to connect remotely. You can add it to the white list if not, but for security reasons this is probably a bad idea - and definitely a bad idea if it is a production server.

Comment: As the WindowsForm application works well, I think that remote connection to the SQL server is not the issue?

Comment: You said "This is working fine on my server" so I assumed you meant you ran the app from there?

Comment: Yes, I ran the WindowsForm app on my server. It worked. Running an ASP.NET Web API using the same connection string on the same server, does not work.